# How to improve Emacs f90 mode function `f90-end-of-block` so that it can handle blocks with block names omitted

Tags: emacs, fortran

In Emacs f90 mode, there are two useful functions `f90-beginning-of-block` and `f90-end-of-block`, (bound to keys `C-M-p` and `C-M-n`,repsectively), which I often use to jump between beginning and end of code blocks (such as function/subroutine/module).
However I found there is weakness in these two functions. For example:

```
module a
contains
  function f()
    write(*,*)
  end function
end module a
```

When placing the cursor at the beginning of `module` and press `C-M-n`, the cursor will jump to the `end function` line, rather than the `end module a` line. The correct behavior appears only after I modify the `end function` line to the `end function f` , i.e., adding back the function name. Since there are many existing codes that often omit function names at the `end function`, I am wondering whether there is an easy improvement to `f90-end-of-block`, so that it can correctly handle the above case.

The original interactive Lisp function `f90-end-of-block` is defined as:

```
(defun f90-end-of-block (&optional num)
  "Move point forward to the end of the current code block.
With optional argument NUM, go forward that many balanced blocks.
If NUM is negative, go backward to the start of a block.  Checks
for consistency of block types and labels (if present), and
completes outermost block if `f90-smart-end' is non-nil.
Interactively, pushes mark before moving point."
  (interactive "p")
  ;; Can move some distance.
  (if (called-interactively-p 'any) (push-mark (point) t))
  (and num (< num 0) (f90-beginning-of-block (- num)))
  (let ((f90-smart-end (if f90-smart-end 'no-blink)) ; for final match-end
        (case-fold-search t)
        (count (or num 1))
        start-list start-this start-type start-label end-type end-label)
    (end-of-line)                       ; probably want this
    (while (and (> count 0) (re-search-forward f90-blocks-re nil 'move))
      (beginning-of-line)
      (skip-chars-forward " \t0-9")
      (cond ((or (f90-in-string) (f90-in-comment)))
            ((setq start-this
                   (or
                    (f90-looking-at-do)
                    (f90-looking-at-select-case)
                    (f90-looking-at-type-like)
                    (f90-looking-at-associate)
                    (f90-looking-at-critical)
                    (f90-looking-at-program-block-start)
                    (f90-looking-at-if-then)
                    (f90-looking-at-where-or-forall)))
             (setq start-list (cons start-this start-list) ; not add-to-list!
                   count (1+ count)))
            ((looking-at (concat "end[ \t]*" f90-blocks-re
                                 "[ \t]*\\(\\(?:\\sw\\|\\s_\\)+\\)?"))
             (setq end-type (match-string 1)
                   end-label (match-string 2)
                   count (1- count))
             ;; Check any internal blocks.
             (when start-list
               (setq start-this (car start-list)
                     start-list (cdr start-list)
                     start-type (car start-this)
                     start-label (cadr start-this))
               (or (f90-equal-symbols start-type end-type)
                   (error "End type `%s' does not match start type `%s'"
                          end-type start-type))
               (or (f90-equal-symbols start-label end-label)
                   (error "End label `%s' does not match start label `%s'"
                          end-label start-label)))))
      (end-of-line))
    (if (> count 0) (error "Missing block end"))
    ;; Check outermost block.
    (when f90-smart-end
      (save-excursion
        (beginning-of-line)
        (skip-chars-forward " \t0-9")
        (f90-match-end)))))
```

Comment: The cross-posted question on the Emacs site is now deleted.

Answer (score 1):

A quick hack is to modify the line that checks the label matching from yielding error message to just yielding a warning message:

```
(or (f90-equal-symbols start-label end-label)
                   (message "Start label `%s' does not match end label `%s'"
```

There is a SO user who posted this solution as an answer, but deleted the answer before I can verify the solution. The reason she/he deleted the answer may be because I commented on the answer saying that another function `f90-beginning-of-subprogram` can handle the case with mismatched labels. But later I found I still need the additional functionalities provided by `f90-beginning-of-block`, which are not provided by `f90-beginning-of-subprogram`.